# How to move navigation bar to more to the right to fit a logo left of the bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to move the navigation bar just over more to the right so I can add a logo left of the navigation text. Float-right wasn't working.

Here is my CSS code.

```
#Main2 {
height:90px;
background-color:ebebeb;

}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:90px;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;


}

li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;

}

li:Hover {
    background-color:pink;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1efef, #fcfbfb);
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#f1efef, #fcfbfb);
  background:         linear-gradient(#f1efef, #fcfbfb);
}
```

Comment: Put up a snippet/fiddle. Just the CSS is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding css properties:

```
Position:relative;
Right:100px;//or however far you want
```

Comment: To what? OP hasn't even given the html.

Comment: To whatever element needs to be moved right!! Down vote seems a bit unfair.

Comment: It worked! I literally tried everything but the obvious. Thanks Richard!

Comment: No problem :) Im glad to have been able to help. This is a great example of how ridiculous the stack overflow community can be.

Comment: @RichardGuy Its not unfair the question wasn't complete & solution was given. You shall get a +1 soon.

Comment: Sorry Ani :( I literally just made a stack account just to ask this question. Honestly, I don't even know what a fiddle/snippet is so I apologize if my question was incomplete :/

Comment: @Samantha Welcome to stackoverflow, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is usually required to complete a web based question.

Comment: Welcome to the community Samantha, you will find lots of people happy to try and help you here :) Ani, you down voted a correct answer because you had a problem with the question. Not cool.